# Sending SMS from Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, network-programming, message

I want to send SMS from my Application that is under developing on Windows Forms Application, The trouble to achieving this task is getting Port Number, I'm suffering by this issue over a week, kindly guide me, I'm sending uploading my code, one thing more is that I'm using Android OS on my cell phone where I have installed SIM card, and device vendor is HUAWEI. thanks a lot in advance......

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GsmCommMain comm;
        int portn = 0;
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _srp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Cross;

            System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort");
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

                StatusLabel.Text = "Just Enterd in foreach Block...";

                if (queryObj != null)
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.UpArrow;

                    object captionObj = queryObj["DESCRIPTION"];//Model Name
                    object capdeviceid = queryObj["DEVICEID"];//Comm port
                    object MaxBaudRate = queryObj["MAXBAUDRATE"];
                    object connstatus = queryObj["STATUS"];
                    object ct = queryObj.ToString();
                    int timeoutsec = 300;
                    StatusLabel.Text = "USB Modem Condition Main Enter Na Ho Saki...";

                    if (captionObj.ToString().Contains("USB Modem"))
                    {
                        _srp.PortName = capdeviceid.ToString();
                        portn = Convert.ToInt32(capdeviceid.ToString().Substring(3));
                        label1.Text = _srp.PortName + " ,,, " + portn;
                        comm = new GsmComm.GsmCommunication.GsmCommMain(portn, Convert.ToInt32(MaxBaudRate), timeoutsec);
                        StatusLabel.Text = "USB Modem Condition Main Entry...";

                        comm.Open();
                        if (comm.IsOpen())
                            btnSMSConnect.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        MessageBox.Show("Not Opening..." );
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Not Opening...";


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e15)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e15.Message);
            btnSMSConnect.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            //comm.Close();
            _srp.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see any "Port number" at all in your code...

Comment: IF you meant "Port Name" you must access the  `PortName` key from the query object: `sPortName = queryObj["PortName"].ToString();`

Comment: well my understanding is that we can obtain port number using this query Win32_SerialPort what I learned in these days You can see a //com port in argument, I thought this is the way I can get the port number kindly guid me in all expects please

Comment: I'm sorry but there isn't any property named "PortName"  defined in Win32_SerialPort

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't read correctly the query. You must get the instance id (the var with `VID_xxx&PID_xxx`), then query all the serial ports, check which one matches and then use the `PortName` of the serial port. This may help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c53b23a4-12c3-43ba-9127-b74450ab874a/how-to-get-more-info-about-port-using-systemioportsserialport?forum=winforms